# Where is the Visual Recognition Module on Watson Studio Lite located?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I can't seem to get  Visual Recognition Module to work
it stuck on this page

[image: Watson Studio]

I am already using the AI/Machine learning module but can't find the Visual Recognition module. Is this a limitation for using Watson Lite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM exited the visual recognition business. The [Watson Visual Recognition service has been deprecated](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-index).